# Like query performance issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, sql-like

I am using like query in SQL Server. Whenever I run query with wildcard in the beginning ('%testdata' or '%testdata%') the query returns result very slow (around 60 seconds). I have tried running same query in MySQL and results were returned instantly (within a second).

I have a very large database and this will increase continuously, I am afraid that after some time like query results will be much slower.

I am using SQL Server 2008 Express.

Anyone have idea why SQL Server returns data slower than MySQL if we run same like query and if there is any alternative for this.

Comment: Since you're `LIKE` contains a leading `%`, you've made it impossible for SQL Server to use any indices. Queries like this will always do a full table scan (or clustered index scan) - no way to optimize this.

Comment: If you can be much more definitive about your search pattern you can increase the performance of the query, For Ex. instead of '%testdata%' or '%testdata' you can give 'testdata%'. Mostly if you use % at the beginning SQL Server will have to do a table scan no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was because of the type of the column I was using. My column type was nvarchar and when I converted that to text or varchar in my select query before applying like query, it started returning results within 10 seconds.

I got this idea when I saw the column type in my MySQL table which was longtext so I thought to convert the column type in my SQL Server database.

Finally I used query something like below:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONVERT(TEXT, col) LIKE '%data%'
```

[Reference Article](http://www.nikhilgaur.com/2014/10/like-in-sql-query-and-its-performance-overhead.html)

Answer (score 4):

Both databases are handling the `like` in the same way.  They are doing a full table scan of the database and comparing values, row-by-row, assuming that you have a basic query:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.col like '%testdata%'
```

Differences in performance could be due to configuration issues, environmental issues, differences in querying, or differences in testing.  Is the hardware on the two systems comparable?  Are both databases configured to take advantage of available memory, disk, and processors?

In terms of environment, is the data really the same on the two systems?  When you do the timings, are you clearing the caches in the system to get comparable timings?

Another factor may be that the query is actually different, and MySQL does a better job of optimizing the query.

When you run the tests, are you looking at time to first result or time to last result?

Based on my experience, I wouldn't expect MySQL to perform so much better than SQL Server on this type of query.

Comment: Same .... Based on my experience, I wouldn't expect MySQL to perform so much better than SQL Server on this type of query.

Comment: i think OP will have quiet lesser data in mysql then SQL Server .. otherewise i have not seen anyone who says MYSql is faster then SQL server

Comment: yes I have same data in both databases MyQSL and MSSQL also result set returned from both queries is same. I was also expecting that SQL server is faster but what what I see what totally different.